# MongoDb - Spring Boot - Enum Type

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, enums

I have a project with Spring Boot and MongoDB. I have an enum class that return Integer. But, as far as i know, enum types saved as String into mongdb. But, i want to saved as Integer. How can i handle this problem.?

Below code my Employee class.

```
@Data
@Document
public class Employee {

    @MongoId(FieldType.OBJECT_ID)
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String department;
    private Address address;
    private Company company;
    private Status status;

}
```

Below code my enum class.

```
public enum Status {

    JUNIOR(0),
    MID(1),
    SENIOR(2);

    private final int value;

    Status(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

- To save an enum as an integer in MongoDB using Spring Boot, you can
  use a custom converter

To create a custom converter for your enum, you need to create a
class that implements the Converter interface and takes your enum
class as the generic type parameter. The following code shows an
example of a custom converter for the Status enum:

```
public class StatusConverter implements Converter<Status, Integer> {

@Override
public Integer convert(Status source) {
    return source.getValue();
}

@Override
public Status unwrap(Integer source) {
    return Arrays.stream(Status.values())
            .filter(status -> status.getValue() == source)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid status value: " + source));
}
}
```

Once you have created your custom converter, you need to register it with Spring Data MongoDB. You can do this by adding the following configuration to your application's spring.data.MongoDB properties:

spring.data.mongodb.converters.enabled=true
spring.data.mongodb.converters.custom-converters=com.example.StatusConverter

Comment: First of all, Thanks for your respnse. But when i research my problem, i found another solution. I am not sure but, i suppose, I can use below annotation.

`@Field(targetType = FieldType.INT32)` 

What do you think about.?

Comment: Yes, you can use the @Field(targetType = FieldType.INT32) annotation to save an enum as an integer in MongoDB. This annotation tells Spring Data MongoDB to store the field as an integer instead of a string

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you can try this

```
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Status status;
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I am not sure your respnonse but, i try to @Field(targetType = FieldType.INT32) this annotation. And it worked.